# What is the significance of the term 'isolated system' in law of conservation of charge?

Tags: electrostatics, conservation-laws, charge

I did not understand why charge can only be conserved in an isolated system. Kindly elucidate.

Comment: There are photons carrying energy to and from every square inch of the universe. There are no isolated systems. You could make the argument that an individual photon is an isolated system or the universe as a whole is an isolated system but everything in between has photons conveying information.

Answer (score 2):

If a system is not isolated then current density could flow in at the system boundary (and not flow out) and thus change the net charge in the system.